# Set colour of series dynamically from an array AM CHARTS

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using amCharts and have the graph working the way I want. I am trying to change the colour of the column series based on a HEX code stored in a dataset. My data is stored in an array:

Array example:

```
colour: "#629632"
dt: "2020-09-03T00:00:00"
max: 0
min: 0
pc: "Dec 20"
data: 25
```

I have the below series and the last three lines are causing me issues. I am trying to set the color of the series based on the array example. I tried rangeSeries.dataFields.color but this doesnt work. It just defaults to a blue. How can I set the colour based on my array 'colour' attribute?

```
       var rangeSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    rangeSeries.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(50);
    rangeSeries.dataFields.dateX = "dt";
    rangeSeries.dataFields.valueY = "max";
    rangeSeries.dataFields.openValueY = "min";
    rangeSeries.yAxis = rangeAxis;
    rangeSeries.tooltipText = "[bold][/]Range: {openValueY} - {valueY}";
    rangeSeries.name = "Range";
    rangeSeries.dataFields.color = "colour";
    rangeSeries.dataFields.stroke = "colour";
    rangeSeries.dataFields.fill = "colour";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rangeSeries.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = "colour";
rangeSeries.columns.template.propertyFields.stroke = "colour";
```